# Can the result of a call trigger the execution of a transaction?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, contract-invocation, ethereumjs

Supposing I have a transaction (A) = a call (B) + other storage operations (C). Executing A, beeing a transaction, I have to pay the gasUsed by B and C.
Beeing B an expensive call and since I need the result of B to verify if is possible to exectue C, is there a way to split A in B and C (call + transaction) with the result of B automatically triggering the execution of C?

Comment: Currently the only option to not pay for B execution is to compute B off-chain. You can send a proof of B execution to C, then C validates the proof an executes the requested operation.

Comment: Is there any tutorial for this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of a tutorial for that task. Depending on B you can try using state channels for off-chain verification. There are more complex protocols like truebit.